# script line works on dc but not while using invoke command

Tags: powershell, command, invoke

i have a variable $user which has an AD user stored in it. 
i want to change its UPN. 
if i write this on dc:

```
$user | set-aduser -UserPrincipalName bla@bla.bla
```

it works fine.
but if i use invoke command like so

```
Invoke-Command -Session $S -ScriptBlock  {$using:ADUSER | set-aduser -userprincipalname bla@bla.bla}
```

i get an error (assume $s is a good session, im using it in other lines)
my error is:

The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its 
properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (CN=uzi,OU=IT,OU...shahar,DC=local:PSObject) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
    + PSComputerName        : dc01

edited: lines for aduser

```
$uname =  $script:textbox1.text+"@"+$script:textbox2.text

$ADUSER = Invoke-Command  -Session $S -ScriptBlock {Get-aduser -property 'emailaddress' -filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$using:UNAME'"}
```

can anyone assist please?

Comment: assuming `$ADUSER` is the samaccountname (e.g. jdoe1234) try `Invoke-Command -Session $S -ScriptBlock  {set-aduser -identity $using:ADUSER -userprincipalname bla@bla.bla}`

Comment: your code does not define `$AdUser` ... please add that to your code so that one can do something lore than make wild guesses ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add a param block to your scriptblok and use that

Something like

```
Invoke-Command -Session $S -ScriptBlock {param ($ADUser, $UPN = 'someone@bla.bla'); $ADUser | Set-ADUser -UserPrincipalName $UPN } -ArgumentList $ADUser, 'bla@bla.bla'
```

or better readable:

```
$scriptBlock = {
    param (
        $ADUser, 
        $UPN = 'someone@bla.bla'
    )
    $ADUser | Set-ADUser -UserPrincipalName $UPN
}
Invoke-Command -Session $S -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList $ADUser, 'bla@bla.bla'
```